# Explanation for the name Rebbi Nechunya ben HaKaneh

Tags: names, tannaim

Is there an explanation the Tanna Rebbi Nechunya's surname ben "HaKaneh" - son of the reed?

Comment: I can't put it as answer because I don't have a source, but I would think it has to do with the fact that he was very humble (see Megillah 28a).

Comment: @Ploni see https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%94

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but that only a theory (just like mine), and IMO not very likely either.

Comment: Maybe _Hakane_ was his father's name? (Maybe it's a transliteration of ῾Ικανός or a calque of Κάλαμος? Per [the LGPN](http://www.lgpn.ox.ac.uk/), both were given names, and, knowing nothing about Ancient Greek names but seeing they were masculine words, I'm guessing they were male names.)