# Who was Rav Nechunya ben HaKanah?

Tags: pirke-avot-ethicsof, tannaim

The Mishna Avos (3:5) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.3.5?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=Chasidut&lang2=en)

> רַבִּי נְחוּנְיָא בֶּן הַקָּנָה אוֹמֵר, כָּל הַמְקַבֵּל עָלָיו עֹל
> תּוֹרָה, מַעֲבִירִין מִמֶּנּוּ עֹל מַלְכוּת וְעֹל דֶּרֶךְ אֶרֶץ. וְכָל
> הַפּוֹרֵק מִמֶּנּוּ עֹל תּוֹרָה, נוֹתְנִין עָלָיו עֹל מַלְכוּת וְעֹל
> דֶּרֶךְ אֶרֶץ: Rabbi Nehunia ben Hakkanah said: whoever takes upon
> himself the yoke of the Torah, they remove from him the yoke of
> government and the yoke of worldly concerns, and whoever breaks off
> from himself the yoke of the Torah, they place upon him the yoke of
> government and the yoke of worldly concerns.

Although his peculiar name (son a the reed) is already questioned [elsewhere](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84059/explanation-for-the-name-rebbi-nechunya-ben-hakaneh), who was Rav Nechunya ben Hakanah specifically in that he seemed to have some personal experience seeing people work and lose their Torah, while seeing others learn and no longer need to work? [Perhaps the role of 'the reed' plays into his profession which he had at one point and gave up for a life of Torah?]

Comment: This experience is very common among people who deal with those who study Torah regularly. I assume many Rosh Kollelim could discuss the matter.

Answer (score 2):

Her is some info that may help you answer your own question.

From Who's who in the Talmud( Shulamis Frieman)

[image]